# Jquery mousewheel event not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-events

using mousewheel for a hero header effect and it is not working on mobile. touch scrolling is scrolling the content behind the hero header and not triggering the mousewheel effect... any ideas how to fix this would be much appreciated!!

```
$('.sd').click(function () {
    $('.hero, .content').addClass('scrolled');
});

$('.hero').mousewheel(function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
        $('.hero, .content').addClass('scrolled');
        return false;
     }
});
$(window).mousewheel(function (e) {
    if ($('.hero.scrolled').length) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0 && e.deltaY > 0) {
            $('.hero, .content').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
    }
});
```

CSS BELOW: not sure if its something in the CSS that is the issue, so have included it below. I am wondering if may have something to do with positioning or z-index but can't be sure...

```
.hero{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9;

    transition: all 1.6s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
            @media (max-width: 740px){
            height: 100vh;
            z-index: -1;
        }
}
.hero.scrolled{
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0) scale(.75);
    opacity: 0;
}
.hero-inner{
    background-image: url(../../assets/plymouth.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    // display: table;
    // width: 100%;
    // height: 100vh;
    // position: fixed;
    // top: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    justify-content: center;

}
.hero-title{
    // display: table-cell;
    // vertical-align: middle;  
    // text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    // margin-top: 10%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    font-family: montserrat;
}
.font-2{
    font-family: 'josefin sans';
    font-weight: 700;
}
.title{ letter-spacing: .3em; text-transform: uppercase; }
.text-light{ color: #fff }
.font-alt{
    font-family: 'georgia';
    font-style: italic;
    color: #666;
}
.hero{
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    // border-top: 1rem solid black;
    padding: 0; 
    margin-top: 2rem;
    transition: all 1.6s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0) scale(.75);
    opacity: 0;
}
.content.scrolled{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);   
    opacity: 1;
}
.sd{
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.sd:hover, .sd:focus{
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Mobile devices dont have "mousewheels". Have you tried using ordinary jquery scroll?

Comment: I believe that in this link below you can find the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32652836/3168107

Comment: Hi @TimGerhard I've tried refactoring to use scroll but console log doesn't bring anything up, not sure where I've gone wrong with the code but the scroll function doesn't seem to be recognized -- keep in mind I am a total jquery/js newb so your patience is appreciated :D

Comment: Hi @EileenChoi Just asking if your question is still open or if you could resolve it yourself. If not I'd be more than happy to help you further with your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use JQuery Scroll as mobile devices have no mousewheels. I wrote you a simple demonstration of how you can trigger the scroll event. 
- removed quotes around $("window")

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.hero.scrolled').length) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0 && e.deltaY > 0) {
            $('.hero, .content').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
    }
});
```

Or for scrolls on a specific element:

```
$(".hero").scroll(function() {
  console.log("scrolled");
});
```

Just ask in the comments if you have any questions. Your issue might also not be scroll related but something different. Maybe it would help if you showed me what exactly you want to achieve