# Mouse wheel event alternative for moblie

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a container has overflow to x axis, i'm doing the scroll event using js
this is scroll code

```js
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.horizontal-scroll');

scrollContainer.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
});
```

And for mobiles the x scroll stops at 992px, so the problem i faced it's in mobile devices that has screen larger then 992px,
It doesn't have scroll wheel to scroll left, and the vertical scroll is closed cause its larger then mobile.

I tried `touchmove` event but it doesn't have deltaY property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v found an answer on a similar question which is [Detect scrolling after scrolling distance from current position in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648789/detect-scrolling-after-scrolling-distance-from-current-position-in-browser/69564572#69564572) and there was useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69564572/15017841) i'v used
So the code i wrote to fix my problem was

```js
let touchstartX = 0
let touchendX = 0

scrollContainer.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
    touchstartX = e.changedTouches[0].screenX;
})

scrollContainer.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
    touchendX = e.changedTouches[0].screenX;
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += touchstartX - touchendX;
})
```